# two tables with text and different height

Tags: tables, tabularx

I am new to latex and I would like to make a table like this:
[image: TABLE]
There are so many packages, that I get lost. tabular, tabular*, tabularx ? Which is the best package that I should use to make a table like this? Is possible to use for example itemize ?
Thanks !

edit:
I changed photo to a more simple and I try this:

```
\begin{tabular}{|p{7.25cm} | p{1cm} | p{7.25cm}|}
\hline
\textbf{Method 1} &  & \textbf{Method 2} \\ [0.5ex] 
\hline\hline
{1.The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog2.The quick brown fox jumps     over the lazy dog} &   & The sky was cloudless and of a deep dark blue. The sky was cloudless and of a deep dark blue. \\ 
\hline
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog &  & The sky was cloudless and of a deep dark blue. \\
\hline
 The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog &  & The sky was cloudless and of a deep dark blue. \\
\hline
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog &  & The sky was cloudless and of a deep dark blue. \\
\hline
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog &  & The sky was cloudless and of a deep dark blue. \\ [1ex] 
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

and I have this:
[image]

It is not the same as the image above, but I am fine if I can change the height of columns. Is there a way ?

Comment: Welcome, please add a MWE showing what you have tried so far.

Comment: For star look https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables amd many examples of similar tables here on site. However, first provide base information about your document and desired result (two tables in parallel? It seems that use of `tabularx` can be good starting point.

Comment: For some like the text showed,  the best is not use tables at all.  Jail the text adds nothing except subtracts elegance and make the typing harder. There are not any advantage here over use just two columns with centered sections, subsections and enumerate lists.

Comment: @AboAmmar  I tried to add a minimal working example and code

Comment: @Zarko I have an A4 article document . What I want, is to put a table like the images in a page. I said two tables because I don't know if I should create one table with a hidden column or two tables and put them parallel. tabularx is complex to me . Thanks for your answers !

Comment: @Fran Thank you also for your suggestion ! You are right that typing is harder. While I can write math functions and types in latex, tables are difficult to me. Nonetheless I would like to add something like a table to distinguish the cases

Comment: @IakobFokas  to distinguish the cases in lists, a little vertical space between items (i.e.,  set ` \itemsep`)  does wonders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing anything about document it is very difficult to provide an usual answer. It is only clear, that you look for something like this:

[image]

which is produced by the following table code (based on your code fragment):

```
\begin{tabular}{|p{7.25cm} | p{0.5cm} | p{7.25cm}|}
    \cline{1-1}\cline{3-3}
\textbf{Method 1}   && \textbf{Method 2} \\ [0.5ex]
    \cline{1-1}\cline{3-3}
    \cline{1-1}\cline{3-3}
{1.The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog2.The quick brown fox jumps     over the lazy dog} 
                    && The sky was cloudless and of a deep dark blue. The sky was cloudless and of a deep dark blue. \\
    \cline{1-1}\cline{3-3}
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog 
                    && The sky was cloudless and of a deep dark blue. \\
    \cline{1-1}\cline{3-3}
 The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog 
                    && The sky was cloudless and of a deep dark blue. \\
    \cline{1-1}\cline{3-3}
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog 
                    && The sky was cloudless and of a deep dark blue. \\
    \cline{1-1}\cline{3-3}
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog 
                    && The sky was cloudless and of a deep dark blue. \\ [1ex]
    \cline{1-1}\cline{3-3}
\end{tabular}
```

however if above code fit to your document, I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but an alternative too long for a comment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol,lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{multicols}{2}\parindent0pt
\hfil\textbf{\large Method 1}\par
\begin{enumerate}
\item\lipsum[1][1-2]
\item\lipsum[2][1]
\item\lipsum[3][1-2]
\item\lipsum[4][1]\vfill\leavevmode
\end{enumerate}
\par\columnbreak
\hfil\textbf{\large Method 2}\par
\begin{enumerate}
\item\lipsum[5][1-2]
\item\lipsum[6][1-2]
\item\lipsum[7][1]
\item\lipsum[8][1]
\item\lipsum[9][1]
\item\lipsum[9][1]
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}
\lipsum[10]
\end{document}
```

Or even with some rules to distinguish the columns, but without jailed sentences:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol,lipsum,adforn,xcolor,enumitem}
\columnseprule1pt
\columnsep4em
\renewcommand{\columnseprulecolor}{\color{gray!20}}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{multicols}{2}\parindent0pt
\hfil\textbf{\large Method 1}\par\hrulefill
\begin{enumerate}[left=0pt]
\item\lipsum[1][1-2]\
\item\lipsum[2][1]
\item\lipsum[3][1-2]
\item\lipsum[4][1]
\end{enumerate}
\hrulefill\par
\vfill
\hfil\noindent\adftripleflourishleft\quad\adfast4\quad\adftripleflourishright
\vfill\leavevmode
\par\columnbreak
 \hfil\textbf{\large Method 2}\par\hrulefill
\hrulefill
\begin{enumerate}[left=0pt]
\item\lipsum[5][1-2]
\item\lipsum[6][1-2]
\item\lipsum[7][1]
\item\lipsum[8][1]
\item\lipsum[9][1]
\item\lipsum[9][1]
\end{enumerate}
\hrulefill
\end{multicols}
\lipsum[10]
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]

What look better?

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. I am really considering to write my document as you suggest. Although I can't mark your answer as accepted, because the question was more specific.

Comment: Do not worry.  Is the typical  "seems a XY question" dilemma:  Someone asked for "Y",  and you guess that probably really want "X". The correct answer is Y,  and your crystal ball could  fail miserably, but  anyway  you must point to X.